# topology: prove that a subset D of a topological space M is dense iff for all x in M there exists a filter that contains D and converges to x

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, problem-solving

for the implication from left to right, my idea is that if D is dense, then it shares elements with any open of M (no intersection is null), the set of neighborhoods of x is a filter that converges to x, if we add D to the mix we won't run in the problem of getting the null set (intersection of 2 elements of the filter is an element of the filter), and the only set that fully contains D is M itself (is it?) so the set of neighborhoods of x reunited with D should be a filter (?)

for the reciprocate, if such filter exists, then D intersects every open that contains x, applying for all x in M we get that D intersects every open of M and therefore is dense.

Comment: (1) "Filter" is a term that has multiple variants to its meaning. While these variants are minor, they do affect how this question can be answered, and we do not know the exact definition you are using. (2) The rationals are dense in $\Bbb R$, but there are plenty of sets that contain all the rationals but are not $\Bbb R$. In fact, the only sets $X \subsetneq M$ that only have $M$ and themselves as supersets are those that differ from $M$ by just one element. You will have to add more than $D$ to get a filter. (3) in the last paragraph, why must $D$ intersect all open sets containing $x$?